# Add a list of presenters to the teams meeting

Tags: microsoft-teams, presenter

We are a team of around 20 people and we take turns to host the meeting, share our screen to run through the tracker everyday. We have configured the tracker to show who the presenter is for the day, but unless somebody opens the tracker, we do not know who is going to be the one for that day. Is there a way to create the meeting invite in teams and define who presents for the day as part of the invite, please?

Comment: Could you please refer this, if it address your scenario? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/50711/how-to-send-meeting-request-wirh-different-sender.html

Comment: Hi Prasad, thank you, but I dont think it helps my case. In my case I want to very simply see who is going to be the person running through the tracker for that day. Ofcourse, I can simply paste the tables with the name and dates into the meeting invite, but that is not the point :)

Comment: Are you looking for any Graph API method to achieve the scenario or you want these to reflect in MS Teams Calendar itself?